# framework to create tooltip (createjs and kineticjs)

Tags: javascript, frameworks, tooltip, kineticjs, createjs

I'm searching for a JS framework that is compatible with CreateJS and KineticJS to create tooltips on a canvas.

I'm making an app that uses both CreateJSs and KineticJS and I want to draw tooltips on both of them (without using two libraries).

Thank you.

Comment: If you are making an App that uses CreateJS AND KineticJS, how do you expect to not use two libraries? KineticJS supports creating Tooltips straight out of the box, so you can integrate that with CreateJS probably.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens (if not hundreds) of tooltip scripts out there—just ask google!

I assume that since you want to support both createJS and kineticJS that you must have already coded the trigger that requests a tooltip.

With that in mind, here is one tooltip library: http://www.opentip.org/documentation.html

- It’s open-source so you can use/modify it freely.
- It’s controlled by javascript so you have createJS/kineticJS independence while still working in JS.
- It uses html canvas to display the tip so customizations should be familiar to you.
- The tip-canvas is temporary and it floats so it should not interfere with your main canvas.
- It allows you to offset the tooltip, so your code can exactly position the tip as you need.